# How can I reuse XAML templates for TreeView items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

In the following example code, I have a WPF tree view displaying two types. It works great. However, the XAML that defines the template for each type is very similar except for the image file that is used. How can I get rid of the duplication? I assume there is a way to define the template separately and use some kind of trigger or something to drive which image to show.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="233">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeFolder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,2,2,2">
                        <Image Source="images/folder.png" Width="13" Height="13" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeNode}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,2,2,2">
                        <Image Source="images/subroutine.png" Width="13" Height="13" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeNode> treeList  = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // set up test data
            treeList.Add(new TreeNode { Name = "Node 1" });
            treeList.Add(new TreeNode { Name = "Node 2" });
            var folder = new TreeFolder { Name = "Folder Node 1" };
            folder.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Name = "Node 3" });
            folder.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Name = "Node 4" });
            treeList.Add(folder);
            folder = new TreeFolder { Name = "Folder Node 2" };
            folder.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Name = "Node 3" });
            treeList.Add(folder);

            treeView.ItemsSource = treeList;
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Test
{
    class TreeFolder : TreeNode
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Nodes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a solution with a converter is possible, I would rather change data structures. I don't think TreeFolder type is necessary

```
public enum NodeTypes
{
    Subroutine,
    Folder
}

public class TreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public NodeTypes NodeType { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Nodes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
}
```

then template can be changed like:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,2,2,2">

        <Image Width="13" Height="13" Margin="0,0,4,0">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Folder">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="images/folder.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Subroutine">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="images/subroutine.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>

        <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you! You were right that I didn't need two different node classes. I can differentiate them with a property that checks if the internal node list is null. If so, it is a sub node, otherwise it is a folder node. Now I dont have duplicate code!

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse Template for both TreeNode and TreeFolder, if create a converter for Image.Source:

```
public class NodeIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TreeFolder)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/folder.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        if (value is TreeNode)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/subroutine.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

add converter in view Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NodeIconConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and mpdify Template:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1,2,2,2">
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" 
                   Width="13" Height="13" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
            <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```